# SELECT $array[$id] in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, select

Now, I know this is bad practice but here is what i'm trying to do.

This is what I have now:

```
$max_str = "MAX(CASE WHEN p_list.p_name";
$case_str = "THEN (CASE WHEN check_box = '2' THEN '2' WHEN check_box = '1' THEN '1' WHEN check_box = '0' THEN '0' WHEN checkbox = '1' THEN '1' WHEN checkbox = '0' THEN '0' END) ELSE '-' END)";

@$result = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT ID, Description, checkbox,

  $max_str = '$row[0]' $case_str '$row[0]',
  $max_str = '$row[1]' $case_str '$row[1]',
  $max_str = '$row[2]' $case_str '$row[2]',
  $max_str = '$row[3]' $case_str '$row[3]'


FROM p_list
JOIN $databasetable
        ON $databasetable.P_ID = p_list.P_ID
LEFT JOIN udata_store 
        ON $databasetable.C_ID = udata_store.C_ID

WHERE p_list.J_ID = $jid and $databasetable.J_ID = $jid
GROUP BY ID");
```

`$row[$id]` contains row values extracted from a different table and they can change all the time. Basically `$id` can go from `0` to `n`.

The query I have now works fine except I have to put the
`$max_str = '$row[0+n]' $case_str '$row[0+n]',` quite a few times (where n is how many rows i put.) so as not to run out of rows.

I want to know how to incorporate a loop inside the query something like that:

```
@$result = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT ID, Description, checkbox,

$i=0;
while($i<$num_of_rows_from_table){
echo "$max_str = '$row[$i]' $case_str '$row[$i]',"
$i++;
}

...
```

Though i don't know how I would deal with the last `,` in the loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by removing last comma.

```
$str = '';
$i=0;
while($i<$num_of_rows_from_table){
   $str .= "$max_str = '$row[$i]' $case_str '$row[$i]',";
   $i++;
}

$str = substr($str, 0, -1);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
$i = 0;
while($i<$num_of_rows_from_table)
{
    // prepend a comma for every element after the first
    if ($i > 0)
        echo ", ";

    echo "$max_str = '$row[$i]' $case_str '$row[$i]'";

    $i++;
}
```